# Jabber based IM services other than gtalk?

Tags: instant-messaging, jabber

What are the other IM services that use Jabber other than gtalk?

Answer (score 5):

Wikipedia ref -- [Free **Jabber Clients**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Free_Jabber_clients).
[**Jabber**](http://www.jabber.org/index.php/about/) uses [**XMPP**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol) -- [List of XMPP client software](http://xmpp.org/software/clients.shtml).
Here is a frequently updated list of registered [Public **XMPP Services**](http://xmpp.org/services/).

> In addition to large, well-known services such as [Google Talk](http://www.google.com/talk/), [Live Journal Talk](http://www.livejournal.com/chat/), [Nimbuzz](http://www.nimbuzz.com/), and [Ovi](http://www.ovi.com/), there are also many smaller services run by volunteers in the XMPP community.

And, [Pidgin](http://pidgin.im/) is a good client.

Answer (score 1):

If you are thinking about deploying your own chat service over your company's intranet, you should look at [Openfire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/index.jsp).

It's very easy to set up (it requires a server with a JVM, if I remember correctly) and it's compatible with all XMPP clients. I set it up 18 months ago and have since forgotten how it works, as it is a 0 maintenance tool!

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear whether you're asking about IM clients (as in the question title) or IM services (as in the question body).

If you're asking about clients, I've been using [Pidgin](http://pidgin.im/) for a few years and like it quite a bit.

Comment: edited question.

Answer (score 0):

A little more context would help. Jabber is a open standard, and well, anyone can run their own, interoperable server, so there's quite a few. However you can run a server on its own, closed off from accounts on other servers. Knowing why you need to know this might help answer your question better.

Most multiplatform clients (empathy and kopete on linux, pidgin on everything it runs on, and miranda on windows) support jabber out of the box. There's also standalone clients like spark